# how to setup 3 laravel apps to use same database

Tags: mysql, laravel, nginx, subdomain, vhosts

i would like some suggestions on this situation:

i have laravel app which uses mysql database and it is located on (ubuntu/nginx) "app.server.com".

when i'am developing new version, i would like that new app be hosted on subdomain "dev.server.com" but use same database as current app (located on app.server.com).

also, once we push development version to live, i would move current version to "old.server.com", dev version to "app.server.com" and clear space on dev for future version.

so:

- dev.server.com - develompent laravel app
- app.server.com - current laravel app
- old.server.com - version of app before current

i would like all apps to use same database.

I guess this could also be done with each app in subfolder:

- app.server.com
- app.server.com/dev
- app.server.com/old

but i need your advice which version (and preferably why) would be better.

Thanks,
Y

Comment: I would not use subfolders, this gives headaches each time you try things like that. Go with subdomains, virtualhosts, and connect your apps to the same database. You should not have any problem except if your database schema has to change between versions.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Shema should not change between versions, so i guess subdomains are my way to go.

Comment: What if it was different domains (different IP's) - then i need some tunnel or something? (i guess this is for another thread)

Comment: Yes, it all depends on your database server security configuration